# How to add the total count on top of Bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, annotations, bar-chart

I want to make a bar graph of Gender column of my data frame (with many rows) and I want to show the count of Zeros and Ones on top of bars. My data frame looks like this.

| HR | DBP | Resp | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 110.9 | 64.0 | 15.2 | 0 |
| 97.0 | 72.0 | 19.0 | 1 |
| 89.0 | 62.5 | 22.0 | 0 |
| 90.0 | 105.0 | 30.0 | 1 |
| 103.0 | 104.0 | 24.5 | 1 |
| 100.0 | 125.0 | 35.0 | 0 |
| 113.0 | 102.0 | 26.5 | 1 |

Also, I want to change 0 to Female and 1 to male, as shown in fig below. I looked similar questions on this website but I am unable to understand the logic. Can someone help me out?

[image: Graph]

The code I used to make this graph:

```py
ax = df_1['Gender'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar', figsize=(7, 6), rot=0)
plt.xlabel("Gender")
plt.ylabel("Number of People")
plt.title("Bar Graph of Gender from Training Set A", y = 1.02)
ax.set_xticklabels(('Male', 'Female'))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
gender = df1['Gender'].value_counts()
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
ax = gender.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, color="b")
ax.set_title("Bar Graph of Gender in Training Set A", y = 1)
ax.set_xlabel('Gender')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Patients')
ax.set_xticklabels(('Male', 'Female'))

for rect in ax.patches:
    y_value = rect.get_height()
    x_value = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2
    space = 1
    label = "{:.0f}".format(y_value)
    ax.annotate(label, (x_value, y_value), xytext=(0, space), textcoords="offset points", ha='center', va='bottom')
plt.show()
```

The output:

[image: Bar Graph]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Seaborn's countplot feature:

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.countplot(df_1, x = 'Gender')
#This next line will label the top of the bar with the item counts 
ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])
ax.set_xticklabels(('Male', 'Female'))
```